# virtual key codes arent detected correctly

Tags: c++, winapi, directx

im trying to write some basic functions for handling the keyboard and the key pressed by the user. Im following a textbook, i created an array for handling all the keys:

```
char keyboardKeys_[256];
```

i also set up a macro for my purposes:

```
#define KEYDOWN(name, key) ( name[key] & 0x80 )
```

now i try to simulate the key 'A' (virtual key code 0x41), in this way:

```
keyboardKeys_[0] = 0x41;
```

but if i try to detect the key pressed it doesnt work:

```
if( KEYDOWN( keyboardKeys_, 0x41 )  )
{ 
    MessageBox(NULL, "key pressed", "MessageBox caption", MB_OK);

}
```

what's wrong here? the messagebox doesnt show up..

thank you in advance.

Ok, i got it, what i tried didnt have any sense at all. Considering my case, i want to simulate the key 'A'. In my array keyboardKeys_, 'A' corresponds to the item number 30, also, in order to keep it pressed i need to set the value 0x80 for this variable. The virtual key code for 'A' is DIK_A

my example then becomes:

```
keyboardKeys_[30] = 0x80;

if( KEYDOWN( keyboardKeys_, DIK_A )  )
{ 
    MessageBox(NULL, "key pressed", "MessageBox caption", MB_OK);

}
```

i hope it can be useful for somebody else, thanks for pointing me to the right direction!

Comment: what is the value of keyboardKeys_[0x41] ?

Comment: `(name[key] & 0x80)` will become `keyboardKeys_[0x41] & 0x80` then what's value of element at `0x41`?

Comment: ok i think i got the solution, my first attemp didnt have any sense, i added my answer for future references. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

step 1

```
you set array position 0 to 65
```

step 2

```
you test bit 7 of array position 65
```

this could not possibly do what you think

Comment: yes, you are right, i first had to figure out how the KEYDOWN works. I added my solution to the post. thank you